# MySQL : How to I, join this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have table like this, and i want to output the result like output table, can anyone tell me how to do it, in MySQL

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left join like so :

```
SELECT tb_session.SESSION AS SESSION, tb_class.CLASS AS CLASS from tb_schedul LEFT JOIN tb_session ON tb_schedule.ID_SESSION = tb_session.ID LEFT JOIN tb_schedul.ID_CLASS = tb_class.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, you can use LEFT JOIN

try it:

```
SELECT tb_session.SESSION, tb_schedul.ID_CLASS FROM tb_session LEFT JOIN tb_schedul
ON tb_session.ID = tb_schedul.ID_SESSION;
```